# Count arrangment such that each person wear different tshirt

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

Few friends are going to a party. Each person has his own collection of T-Shirts. There are 100 different kind of T-Shirts. Each T-Shirt has a unique id between 1 and 100. No person has two T-Shirts of the same ID.

They want to know how many arrangements are there in which no two persons wear same T-Shirt. One arrangement is considered different from another arrangement if there is at least one person wearing a different kind of T-Shirt in another arrangement.

**Example 1 :** If Their are 2(=N) friends and Each of the next N lines contains at least 1 and at most 100 space separated distinct integers, denoting the ID's of the T-Shirts ith person has.

```
3 5
8 100
```

Answer for this case is 4

Explanation : 4 possible ways are (3,8), (3,100), (5,8) and (5,100).

**Example 2 :** If N=3 and collection with each of 3 friends is as follow :

```
5 100 1
2
5 100
```

Then here also answer will be 4 as 4 possible ways are (5,2,100), (100,2,5), (1,2,100), and (1,2,5).

Comment: Do we have no information about the collection of T-shirts of each person? Is the thing we want to know "the maximum number of arrangement"?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo Yes the 3 5
8 100 Is the information about collection of Tshirts with each of the friends

Comment: Then we can just assume that all 4 people have 100 kind of T-shirts, and calculate $100\times99\times98\times97$. Am I misunderstanded the question?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo Firsty their are 2 persons in total in example.Person 1 has tshort collection with 2 tshirts having ids (3,5) and person 2 also has 2 tshirts in his collection with their ids (8,100).Now their are 4 possible combination that person 1 wear tshirt with id 3 and person 2 wear with id 8 and so on

Comment: This question was locked because it was part of an open contest, for what it's worth.